# Finding if two elements in a pre-sorted array sum to equal a certain value

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a homework problem and I'm having some difficulties creating a O(n*logn) solution.  I need to write a function that takes a pre-sorted array and a value to search for.  I then need to find if any two elements of the array sum to equal that value.

I need to create both O(n) and O(n*logn) algorithms for this.

The O(n) was easy to create; however, I am having difficulties creating the O(n*logn) algorithm without adding in some gratuitous code that doesn't actually help in solving the problem.  If anyone could give me some pointers on what I might be missing it would be appreciated.

Comment: @letsc: use two indexes a and b; initialize with a=1 and b=n. Check sum of elements at indexes a and b. If the sum is your target, stop, you found the elements. If the sum is lower, increase a; if it's lower, decrease b. When a=b, stop, there are no elements matching. Because the elements are sorted, you'll only skip pairs which you know aren't candidates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start at the first element, and go sequentially. While that, search for the second element using binary search.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are pre sorted you can use a binary search and a linear search