# Sorted array and finding sum with complexity O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, sorting

We have sorted array `arr[]={2,4,5,7,8,12,16,18,20}`.

We need to find out pair of elements whose addition is `12`, with complexity `O(n)`.

Could anyone help on it?

Comment: This is a badly formed question. Complexity refers to a problem over a set of possible inputs. In this case there is a stated fixed input to the problem. Additionally, this is sounding a lot like a homework problem. Please tag it as homework if this is so. Lastly, you're not asking a clear question. What is it you want, exactly? How much help and in which direction?

Comment: No, don't tag anything as homework, that tag is now deprecated.

Comment: Exercise from CLRS -> almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding if two elements in a pre-sorted array sum to equal a certain value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204487/finding-if-two-elements-in-a-pre-sorted-array-sum-to-equal-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 2):

No solution for you unfortunately, just some things to think about that should lead you in the right direction:

Keeping in mind that the array is sorted, which of the following are true?

```
   arr[x+1] + arr[y] < arr[x] + arr[y]
or arr[x+1] + arr[y] > arr[x] + arr[y]

   arr[x] + arr[y-1] < arr[x] + arr[y]
or arr[x] + arr[y-1] > arr[x] + arr[y]
```

If you think about the answers to these long enough (and maybe draw it), a solution should follow.

Hint for how to start:

Let x = 0, y = n-1.
...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Since the array is sorted, take the sum of the first element (arr[0]) and the last element(arr[8]).
If the sum is greater than 12, then we need to lower the sum, so we replace the largest number by the next largest number(in this case, arr[7]);
If the sum is less than 12, we need to increase the sum, so we replace the smallest number by the next smallest number, (in this case, replace arr[0] with arr[1]). Keep repeating this process until you get the sum you want or the two numbers you are summing up is from the same index in the array.